# Registering Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I installed Visual Studio Express 2012 on my Windows 7. Now I have to register it. I made a Microsoft account, and then I have to fill out a form that assumes I am part of some company. I'm not, and if I don't provide valid information, I can't register. Right now I'm stuck trying to find something that satisfies the Department Name under Business Address, but absolutely nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know how to get through this form, or an alternative way of registering it?

[Here's a pic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/214487)

Comment: Googled "register visual studio express". Found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/16c3f544-8e18-49db-86e8-06833825fc57).

Comment: yeah, I tried it, and it still won't work. I think it's a bug.

Comment: Does it give an error message, or just say "invalid department name"? Did you try real-sounding names like "Sales"?

Comment: It just jumps back up to it every time I submit, and says "undefined" right beside it. - I tried "Media"

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it from Internet Explorer.
Did the trick for me in a very similar situation (trying to register to a Microsoft webinar) - the error "undefined" simply did not appear when using IE.